# Looking for a proof that finite abelian groups are realizable over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I've seen it claimed in a few places that all finite abelian groups are realizable over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I'm as yet unable to find a proof of this written down. Would it be possible for someone to point me towards a book that gives this result?

Comment: What does "realizable over $\mathbb{Q}$" mean ?

Comment: A group $G$ is realizable over $\mathbb{Q}$ if there exists an extension field $K$ such that the Galois group of $K/F$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's theorem 5.1 in Inverse Galois Theory by Malle and Matzat.